# Adding Meta tags to the head of a CMS page Magento 2.3.6

Tags: magento2, layout, template, meta-tags

In order to add the following meta tags to the `home` page I have done the followings:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="https://example.com/media/wysiwyg/abc.png">
<meta property="og:image:type" content="image/png">
<meta property="og:image:width" content="512">
<meta property="og:image:height" content="512">
<meta name="title" property="og:title" content="My title">
```

1. I have created `cms_index_index_selectable_home_Image.xml`and `cms_page_view_selectable_home_Image.xml` under `app/design/frontend/<them_vendor>/<theme_dir>/Magento_Cms/layout/`
2. These are the contents of the XML files:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <referenceContainer name="head">
        <block name="facebookmeta" template="facebookmeta.phtml"/>
    </referenceContainer>
   </page>
```

3. I have created `facebookmeta.phtml` under `app/design/frontend/<them_vendor>/<theme_dir>/Magento_Cms/templates/` and these are the contents:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="https://example.com/media/wysiwyg/abc.png">
<meta property="og:image:type" content="image/png">
<meta property="og:image:width" content="512">
<meta property="og:image:height" content="512">
<meta name="title" property="og:title" content="My title">
```

4. Under `Content > Settings > Pages` I have selected the `home` page and in the `Design tab`, in the `Custom Layout Update field` I have chosen `Image`.

I am using the `Facebook Sharing Debugger Tool` but the `thumbnail image` for the `home` page is not the one specified.

Comment: I think facebook taking first image of your site

Comment: same happening in my case too.. I tried but got no luck

Comment: @GohilRajesh Yes it is taking the first image, the solution is to explicitly define the image and that can happen with adding a meta tag to the head which can be done through custom layout XML.

Comment: @GohilRajesh the part where I am confused is referencing the template file in the layout XML file because the tags can not be directly added to the layout XML file.

Comment: Add through template file and call in xml or directly add code in xml both is same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simpler way, if you just wanted these tags on the home page, would be to programmatically add these meta tags to your `app/design/frontend/<them_vendor>/<theme_dir>/Magento_Theme/layout/cms_index_index.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <meta name="og:image" content="https://example.com/media/wysiwyg/abc.png">
        <meta name="og:image:type" content="image/png">
        <meta name="og:image:width" content="512">
        <meta name="og:image:height" content="512">
        <meta name="og:title" content="My title">
    </head>
</page>
```